# How do you add a background gradient to a gatsby image?

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, gatsby-image

I am using `gatsby-image` and trying to add a dark gradient over the image, but it is not working as expected.

Here's my code:

```
 <Img
    sx={{
      height: "70vh",
      background: "linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5))",
    }}
    fluid={data.tos.childImageSharp.fluid}
  />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using Gatsby Background Image and adding the opacity to 1 !important like so

```
import BackgroundImage from 'gatsby-background-image';
const HeroBackgroundImage = styled(BackgroundImage)`
      width: 100%;
      height: 100vh;
      opacity: 1 !important;
      background-size: cover;
      background: linear-gradient(
        90.26deg,
        rgba(3, 113, 227, 0.9) 17.75%,
        rgba(238, 169, 64, 0.61) 99.89%
      );
      background-size: cover;
    `;
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that - out of curiosity, why is Gatsby Background Image better for background images than Gatsby Image?

Comment: @ColinSygiel  https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-background-image/

Answer (score 1):

### Solution 1 - using gatsby-image

You can solve this problem using `position: relative/absolute` like this:

```
import Img from "gatsby-image"

const Wrapper = styled.div`
  position: relative;
  /* width, height */
`

const Gradient = styled.div`
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0 0 0 0;
  background: linear-gradient(/* your linear-gradient */);
`

const Text = styled.p`
  position: absolute;
  inset: /* position */
`

const Component = () => {
  return(
    <Wrapper>
      <Img fluid={fluid} />
      <Gradient />
      <Text>Gradient over image, text over gradient</Text>
    </Wrapper>
  )
}
```

or, as proposed above:

### Solution 2 - using gatsby-background-image

What has worked for me is to place a `<div>` on top of the `<BackgroundImage>`, and then set `background: linear-gradient()` on that `<div>`:

```
import BackgroundImage from "gatsby-background-image"

const Wrapper = styled.div`
  width: /* your width */;
`
const Gradient = styled.div`
  height: /* your height */;
  background: linear-gradient(/* your linear-gradient */);
`

const Component = () => {
  return(
    <Wrapper>
      <BackgroundImage ...>
        <Gradient>
          <p>Gradient over image, text over gradient</p>
        </Gradient>
      <BackgroundImage>
    </Wrapper>
  )
}
```

Comment: this does not work. it overlaps the text then of all children...

Comment: I've expanded my answer to include more details in the code. The gradient won't overlap the text @RobertO'Toole